# Crystal Reports: Group Footer Summary

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, group-by, footer, summary

I'm trying to build a crystal report and i'm facing issues while inserting summary in group footer. Below is my report structure:-

```
GH#1: CategoryGroup </br>
    GH#2: ItemGroup
        GH#3: ItemName
            [Date] [Count] [Code]
            GH#4: Code
           [@Date] [@Count] [@Code]
            GF#4: Code
        GF#3: ItemName
        [Item Total] [Code]
    GF#2: ItemGroup
GF#1: CategoryGroup
```

This is the final result,am trying to achieve:-

```
CategoryGroup:  CG1 
ItemGroup:  IG1 
ItemName:   I1  
Date    Count   ItemCode
22/9/2013   1   xxx
23/9/2013   1   xxx
24/9/2013   2   xxx
            2   yyy

Item Total      
Count   ItemCode    
4   xxx 
2   yyy
```

I'm unable to arrive at the summary of ItemTotal in `GF#3`. Any suggestions ???

Comment: Have you tried moving your items in GF3 to GF2?